# Is there any way to limit execution of smart contract only to my dapp?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

My dapp will grab some data from client and send it to contract. I want to avoid spoofing of it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Modifiers](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#restricting-access)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract MyContract {
  address mAdmin;

  modifier adminOnly {
    if (msg.sender == mAdmin) _;
  }

  function MyContract() {
    mAdmin = msg.sender;
  }

  function doSomething() adminOnly {
    ...
  }
}
```